# copy (...) from program (gzip '..../data.csv.gz') in Postgresql on windows is failed

Tags: postgresql, csv

My `data.csv` is a large volume and I don't have enough storage in my system for that.
Because of this, I want to import `data.csv.gz` into a table of the database in PostgreSQL.

I tried the following code to import that file.

```
copy origin (...) from program 'gzip D:\Download\data.csv.gz' (format CSV);
```

But I've got this error:

```
ERROR:  program "gzip D:\Download\origin_visit.csv.gz" failed
DETAIL:  child process exited with exit code 1
```

Origin is my table in PostgreSQL.
My OS is Windows 10.
I installed gzip in my system and added its path to the environment.

How can I run the code in PostgreSQL? Is there any way to import `data.csv.gz` to PostgreSQL?

Comment: Not sure where you got `gzip` from, but I would look at the help/man file for it. By default on Unixen `gzip some_file` will try to compress a file to a `some_file.gz` version. I believe you are looking for `gzip -cd some_file`, which decompress  a file to stdout.  I would test this on a smaller file to verify your `gzip` works this way.

Comment: The text of the error message will generally be captured in the database's log file.  Look there.  Alternatively, use \copy rather than COPY.  That way the error message will be sent directly to you.

Comment: @jjanes pretty sure the error is because `gzip D:\Download\data.csv.gz` is failing because the file is already gzipped. With an error something like: `gzip: data.csv.gz already has .gz suffix -- unchanged`